# Wildcard 301 Redirect Using Theme Function

Tags: functions, redirect

Please I want to Redirect Urls using wp theme function.

The both domains are pointing public_html
E.g

```
www.example.com/movies/ to stack.example.com/movies/
```

**and**

```
www.example.com/movies/anything to stack.example.com/movies/anything
```

the `anything` is a wildcard because I have thousands of url so i cant list all of them in there

I insist I need it via theme function, not htaccess

Comment: [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) should help. You could also use a plugin, [Redirection](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), [Safe Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/)

Comment: I need it via via theme function not plugin

Comment: Have a look at the rewrite api I mentioned. It's a function you can use in your theme & does exactly what you're looking for.